# Understanding Trace*

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

Good day,

When trying to understand the *Mathematica*'s evaluation sequence by using standard `Trace` and `TraceScan` commands and their nice visual representations developed in the recent [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5459735/the-clearest-way-to-represent-mathematicas-evaluation-sequence), I faced some ambiguities in their behavior.

First of all, when I evaluate

> In[1]:= Trace[a+1,TraceOriginal->True]

I get

> Out[1]=
>   {a+1,{Plus},{a},{1},a+1,1+a,{Plus},{1},{a},1+a}

All sublists correspond to sub-evaluations (as it is stated in the Documentation). The last expression `1+a` probably corresponds to the result of the evaluation although it is not clearly stated in the Documentation. But what exactly mean expressions `a+1` and `1+a` in the middle of the list? To which evaluation steps of [the standard evaluation sequence](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/tutorial/Evaluation.html) they correspond?

The second oddity is with `TraceScan`. Consider the following:

> In[1]:= list={}; TraceScan[AppendTo[list,StyleForm[#,"Input"]]&,(a+1),_,AppendTo[list,#]&]; list
>
> Out[1]=
>   {**a+1**, **Plus**, Plus, **a**, a, **1**, 1, **1+a**, **Plus**, Plus, **1**, 1, **a**, a, 1+a, a+1}

You can see that the last two expressions in the list are `1+a` and `a+1`. Both are results of (sub)evaluations. But the real output is `1+a` and so I do not understand why `a+1` is at the end of the evaluation chain? And why is no there `a+1` in the middle of the evaluation chain as it was in the case of `Trace`? Is it a bug?

P.S. These results are reproduced with *Mathematica* 7.0.1 and 5.2.

Comment: I think this should be migrated to: http://math.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @RobertPitt This question is not about math. It is only related to *Mathematica*'s internals. As you can see I use as primitive example as possible: evaluation of expression `a+1` in *Mathematica* when `a` is undefined. I am trying to understand what happens inside *Mathematica* when I evaluate this. It seems to be not so simple as one could expect...

Comment: @RobertPitt This is a common misunderstanding. The tag Mathematica refers to the Mathematica program developed by Wolfram Research Inc. It is not equivalent to _Mathematics_ or _math_. See also http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/81152/158668.

Comment: I Knew I was unaware of the questions intended nature which is why i only supplied a comment and not a close or down vote, thanks for clearing that up, i will remember this for the future.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `fp` argument to `TraceScan` is called with two arguments.  The first is the original unevaluated expression.  The second is the result of the evaluation.  In your example, the second `AppendTo` is using the first argument so you are seeing the unevaluated expression.  Change `#` to `#2` and then you will see the results you expect.

Also note that the second argument is *not* wrapped in `HoldForm` (documentation notwithstanding), so in general one must take care to use a function that holds its arguments for the `fp` argument to avoid generating spurious evaluations.

**Comparing Trace and TraceScan**

The behaviour of `Trace` is described in considerable detail in the [Mathematica 8 documentation](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/tutorial/TracingEvaluation.html).  It states that, by default, `Trace` only shows expressions *after* the head and arguments have been evaluated.  Thus, we see a sequence like this:

```
In[28]:= SetAttributes[f, Orderless]
         Trace[f[a, 1]]
Out[29]= {f[a,1],f[1,a]}
```

Only the input expression and its result is shown.  The `TraceOriginal` options controls (quote) "whether to look at expressions before their heads and arguments are evaluated".  When this option is `True` then the output is supplemented with the head and argument expressions:

```
In[30]:= Trace[f[a,1], TraceOriginal->True]
Out[30]= {f[a,1],{f},{a},{1},f[a,1],f[1,a]}
```

The first element of the new list is the original expression *before* the head and arguments are evaluated.  Then we see the head and arguments being evaluated.  Finally, we see the top-level expressions *again*, after the head and arguments have been evaluated.  The last two elements of the list match the two elements of the original trace output.

As the linked documentation states, `Trace` is very selective about what expressions it returns.  For example, it omits trivial evaluation chains completely.  `TraceScan` is comprehensive and calls the supplied functions for every evaluation, trivial or not.  You can see the comprehensive set of evaluations using the following `TraceScan` expression:

```
TraceScan[Print, f[a,1], _, Print[{##}]&]
```

The following table matches the output produced by `Trace` with and without `TraceOriginal`, along with the output of the `TraceScan` expression:

```
Trace   Trace    TraceScan
        Original

        f[a,1]   f[a,1]
                 f
        {f}      {f
                 ,f}
                 a
        {a}      {a
                 ,a}
                 1
        {1}      {1
                 ,1}
                 f[1,a]
                 {f[1,a]
                 ,f[1,a]}
f[a,1]  f[a,1]   {f[a,1]
f[1,a]  f[1,a]   ,f[1,a]}
```

There is certain amount of speculation in this table about which entry matches against which, given that the internals of `Trace` are inaccessible.  Further experiments might give information that adjusts the alignment.  However, the key point is that all of the information generated by `Trace` is available using `TraceScan` -- and `TraceScan` provides more.

Comment: There is still something strange with the output of `TraceScan`. Evaluation `list1 = {}; list2 = {}; TraceScan[AppendTo[list1, #] &, (a + 1), _, 
 AppendTo[list2, #1] &];` gives two different lists: `{a+1,Plus,a,1,1+a,Plus,1,a}` and `{Plus,a,1,Plus,1,a,1+a,a+1}`...

Comment: @Alexey The two lists will differ in general.  Consider `Plus`, which is the second expression to be evaluated (appears 2nd in `list1`) but is the first expression for which evaluation is completed (appears 1st in `list2`).  Similarly, `a+1` is the first expression to be evaluated but the last for which evaluation completes.  It is a tricky business to match up evaluation starts and ends.  [traceView2](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5459735/the-clearest-way-to-represent-mathematicas-evaluation-sequence/5527117#5527117) uses a stack to perform this match-up.

Comment: @WReach Very clear explanation, thank you! The only question remained is about difference between outputs of `Trace[a+1,TraceOriginal->True]` and `list = {}; TraceScan[AppendTo[list, #] &, a + 1]; list`. The first returns a list that contains in the middle two expressions: `a+1` and `1+a`. The first of them seemingly corresponds to an intermediate step of the evaluation sequence *before* applying of the `Orderless` attribute, the second is the result of applying of this attribute. Is it right? But in the case of `TraceScan` I can not find the step of applying of this attribute.

Comment: In addition about the `Orderless` attribute. If we evaluate `Trace[f[a, 1], TraceOriginal -> True]` we get `{f[a,1],{f},{a},{1},f[a,1]}`. But if we evaluate `SetAttributes[f, Orderless]; Trace[f[a, 1], TraceOriginal -> True]` we get `{f[a,1],{f},{a},{1},f[a,1],f[1,a]}`. It is obvious where `Orderless` attribute is applied. So my question remains: why `TraceScan` does not show this information?

Comment: @Alexey Sorry if I keep misunderstanding the question, but it's not clear to me what information is missing from the `TraceScan`.  If I execute `TraceScan[Print, f[a, 1], _, Print[{##}] &]`, I see everything in the trace, plus a bit more.  In particular, the action of `Orderless` is apparent.  What am I missing?

Comment: @WReach In the `Trace` output we have intermediate expression `f[a,1]` that at the next stage is converted to `f[1,a]`. In the `TraceScan` output we have no such intermediate expression. That is the point.

Comment: @Alexey Please see the new section in my response, "Comparing Trace and TraceScan".

Comment: @WReach Wow! This comparison gives me completely another understanding of `TraceScan` than that I had derived from your first comment. I thought that for the `fp` argument `TraceScan` arranges expressions in the order of finishing of their evaluation. But now I see that in really the order is the same. Thank you for the comparison!

Comment: @WReach But now I think that it is not right that `traceView2` does not show the transformation `{f[a,1],f[1,a]}` as a step of [the standard evaluation sequence](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/tutorial/Evaluation.html).

Comment: @Alexey `f` is called as each expression begins evaluation.  `fp` is called as each expression ends evaluation -- but it takes two arguments.  #2 is the result that was just computed.  #1 is the corresponding expression *before* evaluation.  The #1 argument will match an expression that was passed to *some* preceding call to `f` -- but simple pattern matching is not enough to determine which one.  It is necessary to track the evaluation stack.

Comment: @Alexey This discussion would be sooooo much easier if we were in the same room in front of a whiteboard ;)

Comment: @WReach You are right about direct communication but it seems that we currently in very different time zones (at this current moment I am at GMT+5). :)

Comment: @WReach The point I still can not understand is related to last but one line in you table. If I evaluate `SetAttributes[{f, ff}, Orderless]; f = ff;
Trace[f[a, 1], TraceOriginal -> True]` I can see that last but one expression is not a copy of the first expression. It is the result of evaluation of the `Head` and the arguments of the function. If I evaluate `SetAttributes[{f, ff}, Orderless]; f=ff;
TraceScan[Print, f[a, 1], _, Print[{##}] &]` I unexpectedly get what I want: expressions `ff[a,1]` and `ff[1,a]` corresponding to applying the `Orderless` attribute. I don't understand the reason.

Comment: @WReach What I want is to have ability to see every transformation and easily map it to [the standard evaluation sequence](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/tutorial/Evaluation.html).

Answer (score 3):

The first part of the question is easy. 
The expressions `a+1` and `1+a` in the middle of the list are where the `Orderless` attribute of `Plus` fires and the terms are arranged in the default order. 
This is point number 8 in the [standard evaluation sequence](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/tutorial/Evaluation.html) tute.

The "strangeness" in `TraceScan` also occurs in version 8. 
Because, it's a rare command, here's the documentation for `TraceScan`

> [TraceScan](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/TraceScan.html)[f, expr, form, fp] applies f
>   before evaluation and fp after
>   evaluation to expressions used in the
>   evaluation of expr.

Note that if you apply it to the expression `a + 1 + b` you get

```
In[32]:= TraceScan[Print["f \t",#]&, a+1+b, _, Print["fp\t",#]&]
During evaluation of In[32]:= f     a+1+b
During evaluation of In[32]:= f     Plus
During evaluation of In[32]:= fp    Plus
During evaluation of In[32]:= f     a
During evaluation of In[32]:= fp    a
During evaluation of In[32]:= f     1
During evaluation of In[32]:= fp    1
During evaluation of In[32]:= f     b
During evaluation of In[32]:= fp    b
During evaluation of In[32]:= f     1+a+b
During evaluation of In[32]:= fp    1+a+b
During evaluation of In[32]:= fp    a+1+b
Out[32]= 1+a+b
```

From here, it's clear what's happening. `fp` applies after the evaluation - so the final `fp` actually corresponds to the first `f`. It doesn't print until the very end because the subexpressions need to be evaluated first.

Comment: Your explanation of the `TraceScan` behavior is unobvious for me. I need more neat example to find a logic in such behavior. In particular, `Trace[a + 1 + b, TraceOriginal -> True]` gives `{a+1+b,{Plus},{a},{1},{b},a+1+b,1+a+b}`. Do you mean that the second `a+1+b` is the result of evaluation? But it should be only an intermediate expression before applying the `Orderless` attribute. And the result of the evaluation is `1+a+b`.

Comment: I'm not sure how else to explain it (probably because I'm not quite sure why the final `fp` has the unevaluated form that it does). Anyway, compare with an example modified from the `TraceScan` docs:  `TraceScan[Print["f \t", #] &, f[1, 2 + 3], _, Print["fp\t", #] &]`

Comment: Thank you for the answer in any way. Now I understand the position of application of the `Orderless` attribute in the `Trace` output. The only problem remained is about the behavior of `TraceScan`.