# Question on TraceScan

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

The main point of this question is the logic behind the operation of the first argument of `TraceScan` (as well as the associated fourth argument but that is not needed for the problem in question): it sometimes excludes some evaluation steps (which `Trace` with option `TraceOriginal->True` gives) but sometimes it includes them as demonstrated in the following examples. I am interested in understanding the logic behind this behavior and how to force `TraceScan` to give the full set of evaluation steps. This question originally arose in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5459735/the-clearest-way-to-represent-mathematicas-evaluation-sequence/5555279#5555279) thread (see my comments to the answer). The general comparison of the behavior of `TraceScan` as compared to that of `Trace` was given by WReach [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5562126/understanding-trace/5567470#5567470) but it does not answer the following questions:

1.) Why doesn't `TraceScan` give the final expression `f[a,1]` in this
case while `Trace` gives:

```
In[1]:= SetAttributes[traceScan,HoldAll];
traceScan[expr_]:=(list={};TraceScan[AppendTo[list,#]&,expr];list)
In[3]:= ClearAll[f,a];
Trace[f[a,1],TraceOriginal->True]
Out[4]= {f[a,1],{f},{a},{1},f[a,1]}
In[5]:= ClearAll[f,a];
traceScan[f[a,1]]
Out[6]= {f[a,1],f,a,1}
```

2.) And, in the following case, why do both `Trace` and `TraceScan` give the
final expression `f[1,a]` wheras only `Trace` gives the intermediate expression
`f[a,1]` which corresponds to the step of the evaluation before applying the `Orderless` attribute of `f`:

```
In[7]:= ClearAll[f,a];
SetAttributes[f,Orderless]
Trace[f[a,1],TraceOriginal->True]
Out[9]= {f[a,1],{f},{a},{1},f[a,1],f[1,a]}
In[12]:= ClearAll[f,a];
SetAttributes[f,Orderless]
traceScan[f[a,1]]
Out[14]= {f[a,1],f,a,1,f[1,a]}
```

3.) And why in this last case do both `Trace` and `TraceScan` give the final
expression `ff[1,b]` and the intermediate expression `ff[b,1]` which corresponds to the step of the evaluation before applying the `Orderless` attribute of `ff`:

```
In[21]:= ClearAll[f,ff,a];
SetAttributes[ff,Orderless];f=ff;a=b;
Trace[f[a,1],TraceOriginal->True]
Out[23]= {f[a,1],{f,ff},{a,b},{1},ff[b,1],ff[1,b]}
In[24]:= ClearAll[f,ff,a];
SetAttributes[ff,Orderless];f=ff;a=b;
traceScan[f[a,1]]
Out[26]= {f[a,1],f,ff,a,b,1,ff[b,1],ff[1,b]}
```

4.) Is there a way to force `TraceScan` to always give exhaustive
information about evaluation as `Trace` does?

---

**In addition**

Here is another, more informative version of `traceScan` which uses the fourth argument:

```
SetAttributes[traceScan, HoldAll];
traceScan[expr_] := (list1 = list2 = {}; 
  TraceScan[AppendTo[list1, #] &, expr, _, 
   AppendTo[list2, {##}]&]; 
  Column[{list1, list2}])
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Cases 1 and 2.** Citing [the Documentation](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/tutorial/TracingEvaluation.html):

> Normally, ... `Trace` intercepts expressions only *after* function
>   arguments have been evaluated. By setting `TraceOriginal->True`, you
>   can get `Trace` also to look at expressions *before* function
>   arguments have been evaluated.

It seems that setting `TraceOriginal->True` just results in prepending additional information to the default output of `Trace`. As the result, we see unnecessary additional "intermediate expression" `f[a,1]` which in really does not appear in the evaluation chains in both cases as it is shown by `TraceScan` and `TracePrint`:

```
In[1]:= ClearAll[f, a];
SetAttributes[f, Orderless]
TracePrint[f[a, 1]]

During evaluation of In[1]:=  f[a,1]

During evaluation of In[1]:=   f

During evaluation of In[1]:=   a

During evaluation of In[1]:=   1

During evaluation of In[1]:=  f[1,a]

Out[3]= f[1, a]
```

So it looks like a bug in `Trace`.

**Case 3.** In this case everything works as expected because the intermediate expression `ff[b,1]` indeed appears in the evaluation chain as the result of applying of the definition associated with `f`. Nothing unexpected.

**Conclusion.** Both `Trace` and `TraceScan` give exhaustive information about evaluation chain but the output generated by `Trace` can additionally contain misleading "intermediate expression" which is in fact just the initial expression of the chain.